# How to define the key of context in go

Tags: go

Why is the general definition of

```
type key int
type userKey key
```

instead of

```
type userKey int
```

What are the benefits of using the first one?

I see that there is no explanation in the official documentation
Then I see that everyone is using the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type <name> <anothertype>` creates a type whose memory layout is same as  `anothertype` but does not have its methods.

This allows to declare methods on a type that otherwise would not be possible.

e.g. with `type key int` it is possible to implement `fmt.Stringer` with key,

```
type key int

func (k key) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Value of key is %d", k)
}
```

which can be used as

```
func (k key) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Value of key is %d", k)
}

func main() {
    var k key = 20
    fmt.Printf("k: %v\n", k) // k: Value of key is 20

    var intK int = 10
    fmt.Printf("intK: %v\n", intK) //intK: 10
}
```

Comment: I seem to understand